# Why are Xamarin Forms.maps Pin not showing information on click in Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, maps

I have PinsCollection Observablecollection as the itemSource of my forms.map. It loads all the pins in iOS and on tap of each Pin I can see the label and Address. But in Android I can see all the pins, but nothing happens on click of the pin.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something when you click the pin, you could use the `MarkerClicked` .  The `MarkerClicked` event is fired when a pin is tapped.

```
boardwalkPin.MarkerClicked += async (s, args) =>
{
args.HideInfoWindow = true;
string pinName = ((Pin)s).Label;
await DisplayAlert("Pin Clicked", $"{pinName} was clicked.", "Ok");
};
```

You could download the source from the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/pins